# Join where one row should be duplicated

Tags: mysql, join

Struggling to come up with a mysql only solution to this.

Simplified setup:

Two tables:

```
Table A
id | value | price
 1 | 2     | 5.95
 2 | 5     | 7.95
 3 | 30    | 8.95
```

```
Table B:
 color | min_value | max_value
green  |     1     |  3
blue   |     3     | 10
red    |    10     | 35
orange |    25     | 50
```

Based on the definitions from table B, i would like to join the color column onto the data from table A.  I need to know, in this example, the average price associated with all the items in table A by color.  However the definitions can be overlapping (i.e. id 3 is both red and orange).

I know I can use python (in this project's case) to recursively go through each color and pull out the matching values and then the average price, but i would love to simplify this by doing it mysql.

Thanks for any help/guidance!

Comment: So how should it count if something is of multiple colors? For each color once? Or only `1/n` for each of the n matching colors?

Comment: One for each.  So id #3 would exist in both the groupings for red and orange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, the default case in SQL is that if one row from a table matches two rows in the other, you'll get two rows in the result.

```
SELECT color, avg(price)
  FROM A, B
 WHERE A.value BETWEEN B.min_value AND B.max_value
 GROUP BY color
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think i had some superfluous groupings that was causing problems and I assumed it was just not giving me the multiple rows I needed.